# jquery-ui making autocomplete list item draggable?

Tags: jquery-ui

Is this possible to make item from a autocomplete jquery box draggable ?

example : drag an item from one list to another (selecting mp3 files names from one div and drop into another (play list)

Comment: Where does autocomplete come in here? Can't you just use draggable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, what you have to do is append the draggable after the items are created when someone starts typing. One way I did this was by adding the open event (sees when the autocomplete box is opened) and then I select the `ui-menu-items` that are created by autocomplete and I make them draggable. An example can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/2SYXT/